# найти span элемент с классом имеющим определенное слово в имени

Tags: html, jquery, парсер

К примеру есть HTML:

```
<div class="price">
    Цена:    <span class="regular-price">
    <span>7498.00 руб.</span>
        </span>
</div>
```

Как найти все span элементы с словом `"price"` в классе?
Использую такую конструкцию, не помогает.

```
$(this).find('span:contains("price")').each(function(){
    res+=$(this).text()+'<br><br>';
})
```

Comment: так похоже сам и отвечу, вроде часть цен видно. Надо будет разобратся из за моего фильтра не видно остальные или какя то ошибка у меня. использую такой код $(this).find("span[class*='regular-price']")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот такая строка:

```
var spans = $("span[class*='price']");
```

даст все span-элементы с словом `"price"` в классе. Пример кода:

```js
var spans = $("span[class*='price']").each(function() {
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="regular-price">1</span>
<span class="regular-price">2</span>
<span class="price">3</span>
<span class="price">4</span>
```

Ссылки на документацию:

- [Attribute Starts With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)
- [Attribute Contains Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)
- [Attribute Equals Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Ссылка на источник: [jQuery - Find all elements by part of the id attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13670829/5275890)